# Upgrade to 12.10 failed. Now it wont start, hangs

Tags: upgrade, startup, lightdm, services

May have started 2 instances of upgrade (to Quivering Quagga - I call it that because my machine is now extinct), stops and hangs halfway through startup.

Always at same point.  Can I work out the order of what is loading and work out which service is failing by determining the last successful service to startup?

My Edubuntu graphic logo doesnt show but a character Kubuntu with the 4 rotating dots ..

Answer (score 1):

We need some log info...
You can also try hitting the arrow keys early in the process - that usually brings up the text output from the startup process. If anything seems suspicious in the output, and it says something like `Error reading so and so` or `Could not initialize the thingamabob`, then tell us about it.

If that log info can't be accessed, try looking at the end of /var/log/kern.log

To do that, boot up into the live DVD, mount the partition for of your new installation, pop open a terminal, type `sudo su`, and type `tail /media/ubuntu/[insert partition name here]/var/log/kern.log`. Tell us what it says.

Also, make sure it's not running a disk check. I've been caught by that one. Is your hard drive light (if you have one) continuously blinking?

Comment: OK Kern is about 37k lines long even the last startup is over 1000 lines ... there are a few interesting things that happen on the screen.
The hdd is not running I have skipped past the disk checks (the main disks are OK).
It kept trying during the course of Saturday while I was out and this kept repeating all day in the kern.log:
Oct 26 21:28:43 ubuntu-10 kernel: [16676.206105] db2fmcd[5002] general protection ip:7fc9c45036c4 sp:7fff86c44ad0 error:0 in libc-2.15.so[7fc9c4495000+1b5000]
Oct 26 21:29:43 ubuntu-10 kernel:... where can I post the file?

Comment: Actually the computer is not dead .. when I CTRL ALT DEL it shuts down gracefully and restarts.  I have installed 12.10 as a second installation on another partition, but I really dont want to find all those packages again, reinstall them, configure them ... :(